# How do I modify my Google App Query formula to convert empty cells in every row of a specific column to be numeric format?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Im trying to filter a data from another spreadsheet. This is the query of what I'm trying to filter:

QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col14, Col12, Col10, Col23, Col16, Col13, Col37, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'")

Output of the original query. Col37 is column H. Please check column H in image, which has empty cells.

Apparently, the cells in every row of column H are not consider to be numeric. I can't compromise the original sheet. So, how do I modify my query to convert empty cells in every row of column H to be in numeric format like with this function  `=n(H3:H)`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Workaround:

You may be able to split up the queries into three arrays and join them back using `{array1,array2,array3}`:

- The first array for all columns before `Col37`
- The second array for `Col37`. Here, you try to coerce all empty cells to 0 using  double unary operator `--`
- The third array for all columns after `Col37`

#### Snippet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col14, Col12, Col10, Col23, Col16, Col13 WHERE Col2='instagram'"),

  IFERROR(--QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col37 WHERE Col2='instagram'"),QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col37 WHERE Col2='instagram'")),

  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col2,Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'")
})
```

#### Performance Considerations:

- Using 4 queries is expected to hit performance rather than a single query
- However, I expect all `IMPORTRANGE` to be cached avoiding 4 different calls.
- Although you mentioned you are unable to modify the source sheet, Modifying the source sheet is a better solution: Modify the source sheet formatting and make empty spaces 0 in the source sheet and a single query in the  destination sheet.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function in google sheets accepts only **one** data type per column:

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type
> determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority
> data types are considered null values.

and this is the reason your query returns **empty** cells for column H.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an approach to **convert only** a single column in google sheets to a different data type **within the query function**. But I do know approaches where you can **convert** the **full input** matrix to **another data type** with the solely purpose of having a **unique** data type per column.

So now you have two options. Either you convert everything to a numeric value, but this will probably drop an error since text values like `instagram` can not be converted into a numeric type. Or you can convert to text the full array so you can at least get the **desired/complete** result back.

The sacrifice of this approach is that column **H** won't be numeric. But at least you have **full** the data in your sheet and you can **explicitely convert only column H to numeric data type** with the [Values](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220?hl=en) function.

---

### Workaround to get the full data back:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Staffing Data 0!A:AS")),
"SELECT Col1, Col14, Col12, Col10, Col23, Col16, Col13, Col37, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'"))
```

and then

`=VALUES(H3:H)`

to get the values of column H as numeric values.

Comment: I think the OPs intention is to convert column ```H``` to numeric values rather than to text @Marios . He would rather need to use [N](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357) only for column ```H```.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf That is the intention, true. However, AFAIK there are two ways to achieve that. Either you convert everything `to_text` or everything to `value`. However, it is not possible to convert a text into a value. But you can convert a number into a text. This is why I am advicing him to convert everything into text. The optimal solution would be to convert only column H to numeric type but like I said, I don't think that's possible (in a query).